# PageYOffset explaination

Tags: javascript

can someone please help me & explain this example for the pageYOffset?

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument;
var info = document.getElementById("info");

var target = frameDoc.getElementById("overview");
frameDoc.scrollingElement.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;

info.innerText = "Y offset after scrolling: " +
                 frame.contentWindow.pageYOffset + " pixels";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset

I'm trying to apply it to on my page but it doesn't work.
I'm getting this error:
**app.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined
at app.js:23**

JavaScript

```
// Get the offset position of the navbar
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll("allSections");
const allSectionsDoc = allSections.contentDocument;

const section = allSectionsDoc.getElementById("section1");

allSectionsDoc.scrollingElement.scrollTop = section.offsetTop;

section.innerText = "Y offset after scrolling: " +
                 allSections.contentWindow.pageYOffset + " pixels";
```

HTML

```
<div id="allSections">
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class section">
      <div class="landing__container active">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What specifically is your question? `pageYOffset` is described as *"the number of pixels the Document is scrolled vertically within its containing Window"*, so when you scroll down, it is telling you how far within that Window you are from the top.

Comment: i edited the post, i appreciate it if u can help

Comment: You are likely getting the undefined error due to your code running before the page is loaded. Try adding the following - window.addEventListener('load', yourFunction, false);

Comment: what can i add in the yourFunction parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', getNaveBar, false)

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var getNaveBar = function(){
     const allSections = document.querySelectorAll("allSections");
     const allSectionsDoc = allSections.contentDocument;

     const section = allSectionsDoc.getElementById("section1");

     allSectionsDoc.scrollingElement.scrollTop = section.offsetTop;

     section.innerText = "Y offset after scrolling: " +
             allSections.contentWindow.pageYOffset + " pixels";
}
```